# Give organizations access to different features in Express.js

Tags: express, authentication, auth0

I'm creating an Express.js API for my application and website, in a B2B model.
I'm using Auth0 with the Organizations feature to separate my clients and their users.

For each organization, they choose a plan for which features they require. I have a role-based system with scopes to access different routes per user, (administrator, accountant, user etc.), but each permission should also be restricted by the features allowed for their organization.

My company delivers a way to organize the vehicle fleet of other organizations, but depending on the feature set, each vehicle will contain different data.
Therefore, I do not wish to block the /createVehicleRoute, only customize it based on organization-level permissions. This creates an issue where a middleware would simply block the call.

How can I achieve this "union type" token claim where you need BOTH i.e. an admin role AND a company "hasFeature": true to customize the controller?